# How to disable timeout in LLDB?

Tags: lldb

In LLDB console, my process is stopped. I run `thread step-in` and eventually get:

`Command timed out`

How do I extend or disable this timeout?

In my case, this timeout is expected it because the program requires external interaction before going to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

`thread step-in` has no timeout.  That wouldn't make any sense, as your last comment demonstrates.

The `print` command can take a timeout, but by default does not.  If you run `po` the object description printing part of that command is run with a timeout.  And if you have any code-running variable formatters, they are also run with a timeout.  lldb has removed most of the built-in code-running formatters, though there a few of them still around and they could also be responsible for the timeout message.  But other than printing, there aren't really that many things lldb does with a timeout...

Anyway, what you are probably seeing is that after the previous stop happened some code was being run to present locals or something similar and that command was what timed out.

If you can get this to happen reliably, then please file a bug with http://bugreporter.apple.com.